# Как выбрать какое подключение к сети интернет использовать для Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

Например у меня есть 2 подключение к сети в компе
Нужно в Python-е с Селеной выбрать сеть для подключение к интернету.
Помогите пожалуйста!